# how to communicate data between forms?

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to pass some values to different forms at there button click event. plz guide me.I am using c sharp.net 2005,win forms. I want to access the value in a sql query in form 2 received from form 1 variable.

Comment: Can you post some more code? If form2 is a class level variable in form 1, then you could use a function. You could do some messaging... Without some more code, it's hard to guess you project setup and help you finding the right direction

Comment: The question isn't MSSQL related, it doesn't matter that the content you want to transfer is used in a SQL query later

Comment: PLease explain your problem in more details, you have two forms and you want to access fields from one to other form ?

Comment: Form 1 is private form and also form 2....I want to pass the data after login is successful... the form 2 will display the username and the company name generated by the successful login by form 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several options:

- pass the data to the constructor of the child form
- expose a instance property in the parent form, then pass that form as an argument to the child form
- expose a static property in the parent form

Answer (score 1):

Use delegate. Thats the best way you could talk. Or as suggested, if form2 is a child of form1, then ctor argument based. If its 2 independent, then delegates.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass it through the constructor of the child form if the data is mandatory, or through a property if it is optional.

Comment: Obviuosly, you cannot pass data (mandatory or not) through the constructor of Form2 if Form2 is already constructed at the time when the user enters the data to be passed in Form1.

Comment: I dont have a child form. These two forms are separate forms. The only dependency between the two is that form 1 acts like a Menu which contains specific buttons which make another form visible by the button click event

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, you have to do something like following code :
inside this event you have to pass data to other

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 secondForm = new Form2();
        secondForm.YourProperty = "This is your data";
        secondForm.Show();
    }
```

In the other form you have to declare a property :

```
    public string YourProperty { get; set; }
```

hope this help.

Comment: I dont want to create dynamic forms at runtime. Form 1 and Form 2 are designed by specific buttons. Form 1 is the menu form while form 2 is the form displayed after a button click event is fired.

Comment: This is a sample Arush, Assume this button's event handler is in your first form, when user comes and clicks on your particular button this event will fire, then create a instance of your Second Form and pass your data finally show the form2.

Comment: I will try this and let u know if prob persists

Comment: You said this "I want to access the value in a sql query in form 2 received from form 1 variable", this sample is what exactly you want.